# Grammar error in close-dialogue

Tags: discussion

So this is surely not the most important problem ever, but ever since I noticed I cannot unsee it.
Shouldn't the close-question dialogue window (see screenshot below) not rather say:

> This question doesn't meet **an** Academia Stack Exchange guideline.

as "Academia" starts with [a vowel](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm)?

[image]

Comment: This is a general problem. See [this Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349877/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft and there is nothing anyone can do about it?

Comment: Well, you need to convince SE to consider this worth the effort. Maybe have a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/255554).